# Filter string and return values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple variables

```
var string = 'this is string id="textID" name="textName" title="textTitle" value="textVal"';
var id, name, title, value;
```

I need to filter `var string` and get values for this variables `id, name, title, value` 
How to do this?

Comment: What were your attempts? `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved`

Comment: I don't know what function should i use.

Comment: You'll probably want to use regular expressions, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: You better directly specify var id='textID', name="textName", ... and then compose string ?

Comment: @jacouh the values are variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this function, as all your attributes have the same form, this works:

```
//
// inputs:
//   strText: target string
//   strTag: tag to search, can be id, name, value, title, ...
//
function getTagValue(strText, strTag)
{
  var i, j, loffset = strTag.length + 2;
  i = strText.indexOf(strTag + '="', 0);
  if(i >= 0)
  {
    j = strText.indexOf('"', i + loffset);
    if(j > i)
    {
      return strText.substring(i + loffset,  j);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

//
// main:
//
var string = 'this is string id="textID" name="textName" title="textTitle" value="textVal"';
var id, name, title, value;
console.log(string);

id = getTagValue(string, "id");
console.log(id);

name = getTagValue(string, "name");
console.log(name);

title = getTagValue(string, "title");
console.log(title);

value = getTagValue(string, "value");
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the values by their indexes. Like I've done below:

```
var stringValue = 'this is string id="textID" name="textName" title="textTitle" value="textVal"';


var indexOfID=stringValue.indexOf('id'); // find the index of ID

var indexOfEndQuoteID=stringValue.indexOf('"',(indexOfID+4)); // find the index of end quote 

var ID=stringValue.substring((indexOfID+4),(indexOfEndQuoteID)); // fetch the string between them using substring

alert(ID); // alert out the ID
```

Similarly you can do for other elements. Hope this helps..!

Comment: nice , but what does meaning `+4` in `indexOfID+4`?

Comment: as you have to fetch the end quote you need to skip first one.. indexOfID+4 will tell indexOf() to start looking for a quote after the first quote.. Are you getting me? you can refer this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Comment: As the index will be fetched at "i" of the "id".. you will have to skip d=" (three charactors)